# microsoft band Web call

Tags: windows-phone, microsoft-band

I just started developing for the microsoft band, but cant seem to figure out how to make external web calls. For example to scrape the html source of a web page.

All the code I have tried so far has simply failed with the same error.

EDIT: Would be great if someone has a working demo already

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: > Notifications.WindowsPhone.exe!Notifications.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__2(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 50 C#

Comment: Post the code you've used and the inner exception and/or stacktrace :) add the windows phone tag as well to the question as I assume the calls are in the app or bg task (viewer reach)

Comment: I do not have any code right now as I cleared it all. But basically any code that tries to make a call to get a web pages source code seems to result in the above error occuring

Comment: Additionally, this sounds more like an issue with your usage of the [Windows Phone API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/mobile-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application) and not the use of the Band API (based on the fact that `Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` is an UI based execption.

Comment: Not sure, really at this point would love to just get an example code from some one about making a web call. I have tried almost everything I can of.

Answer (score 1):

The band itself can not execute such code, but your phone can.
With the TileManager: create a new tile.
Add a page to that tile.
On the page you then add a button with a specific element id.
Add the tile to your band and use the TileManager to set your pages to the tile.

Use the TileManager to hook up to one of the three events (TileOpened, TileClosed and TileButtonPressed).

When using the latter; use the event arguments to find out if the element id for the pressed element is the same as you expected.
If the ids match (if you have multiple buttons and want to distinguish): execute your web call and when the data is retrieved, use the NotificationManager to send data to the Band.

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned, but now get the following error, "An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in SYSTEM.NI.DLL but was not handled in user code
"